# setTimout to a function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, settimeout

I thought you might help me set a timeout for this function. A timeout I've set seems to disrupt the loop.

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
        var earthquake = results.features[i];
        var coords = earthquake.geometry.coordinates;
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            icon: getCircle(earthquake.properties.mag) 
        });
        map.panTo(latLng);
    }
}
```

SOLVED: by defining a function to carry on the variables

```
window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {
       var earthquake = results.features[i];
       var coords = earthquake.geometry.coordinates;
       var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1],coords[0]);
       (function(i, earthquake, coords, latLng) {
         setTimeout(function() {
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: latLng,
           map: map,
           icon: getCircle(earthquake.properties.mag),
           animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP });
         map.panTo(latLng);
         }, i * 400);
       }(i, earthquake, coords, latLng));

    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `setTimeout()`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for editing. I tried enclosing the var marker part with the timer. Works for the first iteration but then the loop stops.

Comment: You need to describe a bit what you want to do. I can't think of a reason to use a timer.

Comment: the total code displays markers on a google map according to lat, lon and concentration value extracted from a file on the web. I want the markers to appear gradually instead of appearing all at once

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you? Of course, you would have to pass in valid data in the results variable for the callback execution to work properly.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.eqfeed_callback(results)
}, 4000);
```

Comment: Hi, the results are used immediately within the function